# [Vue warn]: Property or method "first" and "last" is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm trying to create a website where I have a first and lastname form, and I want it to then display whatever the user types in the textboxes onto the webpage, where it says 'First name:' and 'Last name:' But it keeps saying 'first' and 'last' is not defined eventhough I have defined what it is and where it needs to be used.

I'm not so experienced in vue js and I'm very confused with my code, I'm afraid of changing variables because I tried before and I kept getting more errors that I couldn't figure out. Could anyone please help me out?

Also I'm new to GitHub, I would appreciate it a lot if someone can guide me on what I need to rename or change.

Here's the code I'm working on where it seems to have issues:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <img class="logo" src="./assets/bt-logo.png"/>
            Tracerouter 
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
      <RobotBuilder />
          <ul> 
            <li class="output1">First name: {{this.first}} </li>
            <li class="output1">Last name: {{this.last}} </li>
          </ul>
        <form class="form" action="/action_page.php">
          First name: <input class="text1" type="text" name="fname"> 
          <input class="button1" type="submit" value="First name">
          Last name: <input class="text2" type="text" name="lname">
          <input class="button2" type="submit" value="Last name"> 
      </form>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.0.3/dist/vue.js"></script>

<script>
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data () {
      return {
        first: "Taran",
        last: "Basi"
      }
    },
    methods: {
      giveName: function() {
        return this.first
      }
    }
  })
</script>

<script>
//HomePage from './home/HomePage.vue'
import RobotBuilder from './build/RobotBuilder.vue';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    RobotBuilder,
  },
};
</script>

<style>
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(107, 2, 168), rgb(255, 255, 255));
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  width: 1024px;
  min-height: 300px;
}
header {
  background-color: rgb(107, 2, 168);
  width: 1084px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
ul {
  padding: 3px;
  display: flex;
}
.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  font-size: 22px;
  border-right: 0.5px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.logo {
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 50px;
}
.button1 {
  background-color: rgb(107, 2, 168); 
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: static;
}
.button2 {
  background-color: rgb(107, 2, 168); 
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: static;
}
form {
  display: flex;
  margin: 100px;
  align-items: center;
}
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(107, 2, 168), rgb(255, 255, 255));
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  width: 1024px;
  min-height: 300px;
}
header {
  background-color: rgb(107, 2, 168);
  width: 1084px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
ul {
  padding: 3px;
  display: flex;
}
.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  font-size: 22px;
  border-right: 0.5px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.logo {
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 50px;
}
.button1 {
  background-color: rgb(107, 2, 168); 
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: static;
}
.button2 {
  background-color: rgb(107, 2, 168); 
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: static;
}
form {
  display: flex;
  margin: 100px;
  align-items: center;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using data properties, or calling methods in your **template** you don't need to use `this`,  so your code for first and last names here should be like this.

```
 <ul> 
   <li class="output1">First name: {{first}} </li>
   <li class="output1">Last name: {{last}} </li>
 </ul>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html

Also you have a problem with how you are defining your data object in your main Vue instance. In the main instance it **should not** be a function.

```
<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data :{
    first: "Taran",
    last: "Basi"
  },
  methods: {
     giveName: function() {
       return this.first
     }
    }
})
</script>
```

When defining data in a component is when you define it as a function. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

```
<!-- for components data must be a function -->
data(){
   return {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I removed 'this' and it's exactly how you recommended it but the site still has the same issue

Comment: Ah ok I see another issue now see my updated answer.

Comment: Oh yes I thought I wrote the data object wrong, I changed it now but the same issue is still happening.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?  It should work just as you have it.  See here https://jsfiddle.net/skribe/wL3nyz4a/4/   Perhaps you have an error in your `RobotBuilder` that is causing your issue.

Comment: I see other issues too that I cant quite understand what you are trying to do.  Do you really want the buttons after first name or last to submit the form?  Usually you would want to use ajax to submit entered values rather than redirecting away from your vue app.

Comment: I know I'm sorry I messed up the variable names and made the entire code confusing. I actually wanted it so when the user types in their first and lastname, and presses the first name or last name button, it should submit the form and display what's been entered on the webpage. So yes I would use ajax so submit my entered values.

Comment: I do have errors in Chrome's console, but it just says there's errors mainly in the App.vue file. Everytime I open the RobotBuilder.vue file it says theres no errors in there.

Comment: I am not sure we can help you here as there are some many things that have to be done.   Here is an updated fiddle of how I would get started. https://jsfiddle.net/skribe/wL3nyz4a/20/  I suggest you look up some basic tutorials and go through them.

Comment: That's ok, thank you again for all the help you've given